# Which Node.js version should I choose?

Tags: node.js, azure

I want to create an Azure Web App which will run my React.js app.
Now I have to choose an appropriate Runtime Stack.
Their are a few Node versions where I can choose for.
I have my React App in Node V10.13, but this version is not in the list of the Runtime Stack options.

Does anyone know which version I have to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports upto [V10.14](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/150), you can find it from the portal when you create the web app.

[image]

Comment: I know of which versions I can choose from, but because my react app has node v10.13 I had the question wich version I should choose

Comment: thats my answer too, you can choose 10.13 and above

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted it otherwise ^^. Thanks for the help :)